# Stringbuilder in foreach slower than in for and String.Join() SUCKS on collections?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, string

Having seen a question here on SO, about joining strings I have done some testing and came to knowledge that joining a string in a foreach is slower than with a for loop and using the indexes in the array. Shouldn't a for loop be slower because of bound checking on the array? (bound checking on strings[i] which is not present on foreach).

Another thing I don't understand is string.Join() slowness on lists...

EDIT: Updated the error and updated source to final source (removing the last ",")

Here is the result of the test:

> ```
> DEBUG:
>    AMD PHENOM II X4 3GHZ
>     StringBuilder foreach System.Action Time: 4077ms (12025926)
>     StringBuilder for System.Action Time: 4032ms (11895082)
>     String.Join System.Action Time: 5338ms (15744918)
>    INTEL XEON W3503 @ 2.4GHZ / 12GB DDR3
>     StringBuilder foreach System.Action Time: 4661ms (10926950)
>     StringBuilder for System.Action Time: 4202ms (9849590)
>     String.Join System.Action Time: 6466ms (15156149)
>
> RELEASE:
>    AMD PHENOM II X4 3GHZ
>     StringBuilder foreach System.Action Time: 3897ms (11496978)
>     StringBuilder for System.Action Time: 3719ms (10970899)
>     String.Join System.Action Time: 5307ms (15655162)
>    INTEL XEON W3503 @ 2.4GHZ / 12GB DDR3
>     StringBuilder foreach System.Action Time: 4533ms (10625128)
>     StringBuilder for System.Action Time: 4168ms (9770765)
>     String.Join System.Action Time: 7173ms (16813036)
>     (why in the world xeon slower than in debug with string.join?)
>
> FOR A GOOD LAUGH LOOK AT THE END.
> ```

And here is the source:

```
public static void Main(string[] Args)
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>() {};
    for (double d = 0; d < 12000; d++) {
        strings.Add(d.ToString());
    }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Performance(() =>
    {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in strings)
            {
                sb.Append(s);
                sb.Append(",");
            }
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
    }, "StringBuilder foreach");

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Performance(() =>
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int max = strings.Count-1;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(strings[i]);
            sb.Append(",");
        }
        sb.Append(strings[i]);
    }, "StringBuilder for");

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Performance(() =>
    {
        string s = string.Join(",", strings);
    }, "String.Join");


}
public static void Performance(Action fn, string prefix)
{
    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        fn();
    }

    timer.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} Time: {2}ms ({3})", prefix, fn.ToString(), timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, timer.ElapsedTicks);
}
```

Are strings getting copied like value types in the foreach? Since the speed is practically the same...

EDIT:

To clarify why `int max = strings.Count-1;` could be an optimization contrary to what people say (and test proves that is):

We are not working on arrays and the collection comes from an outer scope to the method that iterates over it. If it were strings.Length in the for loop, that could change (like another thread changing the collection).. but that is not the reason, the reason is that we are reading a variable and not calling a method (property get) and it gives merely 5% performance. That is not a compile time optimization for bound checking since nobody can know in advance the "max" value. It depends on what would be the content of strings in each call to the method.

EDIT2:

Did a test in release with a bigger string but the same amount, please have a laugh at String.Join():

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() {};
for (double d = 0; d < 12000; d++) {
    strings.Add("ikugluglizuglkuhiugpiugiugholiugholiughpiuhziuhzuiugloiu" + d.ToString());
}

// AMD PHENOM:
//     StringBuilder foreach System.Action Time: 10080ms (29732687)
//     StringBuilder for System.Action Time: 9659ms (28490593)
//     String.Join System.Action Time: 24509ms (72292291)
// INTEL XEON:
//     StringBuilder foreach System.Action Time: 9790ms (22947294)
//     StringBuilder for System.Action Time: 9140ms (21425490)
//     String.Join System.Action Time: 21114ms (49490839)
```

It may be good for arrays but at collections String.Join sucks brutally, more so for big strings!

Just for reference if you wish to compare:

```
Windows 7 64bit
CPU Type    QuadCore AMD Phenom II X4 945
CPU Clock   3000 MHz
L3 Cache    6 MB  (On-Die, ECC, NB-Speed)
North Bridge Clock  2010.8 MHz
Memory 8190 MB
Memory Bus  804.3 MHz DDR3-1600
Motherboard Chipset AMD 790X, AMD K10
Memory Timings  8-9-9-24  (CL-RCD-RP-RAS)
Command Rate (CR)   1T
```

Comment: marjino, strings are _not_ value types.

Comment: or you can comment on how slow the String.Join is on lists - on arrays it is pretty fast.

Comment: foreach involves the creation of an instance of the Enumerator for the collection, which for loops do not involve.  Bounds testing is involved in both operations, in some manner or another.  Also, `for(int i = 0;i <= array.Length;i++)`

Comment: Strings are reference types. Also, your `for` loops ends one step too early.

Comment: The for loop test is missing the last string.  Try `int max = strings.Count;`

Comment: @Marino Šimić: No, strings are not value types. There is an error in your test that should be corrected before you can draw any conclusions. You are looping from 0 to max-1, and as max is already string.Count-1 you are omitting the last item in the list.

Comment: it is missing it for a purpose (there was a concatenation of a last item without a comma wich i removed.

Comment: @Marino: But in the foreach it's not missing.

Comment: updated the code, not changed much, the question still remains, and I'm disproving the int max does not optimize, IT DOES

Comment: You are not doing GC.Collect before the foreach test.  That might put foreach at a disadvantage if GC happens during the loop.

Comment: Ill update give me a minute. - done: no change whatsoever...

Comment: Look at the IL code in ILSpy.  The foreach loop has an implicit try .. finally that the for loop does not.  Also inside the foreach there are implicit calls to MoveNext.  MoveNext has a lot of overhead, including a version change check before it finally does an index operation on the list to get the entry.  In theory foreach can be faster, but it clearly does more work than a bare for loop. This is under vs2010.  Not sure how other versions handle this.

Comment: the foreach is doing a try catch? that is not the definition of fast i expect... clearly then a foreach can be faster than a for only if not doing it repeatedly but few times and on long loops?

Comment: @shsmith can you post this comment as an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the IL code in ILSpy.

The foreach loop has an implicit try .. finally that the for loop does not.

Also inside the foreach there are implicit calls to MoveNext. MoveNext has a lot of overhead, including a version change check before it finally does an index operation on the list to get the entry.

In theory foreach can be faster, but it clearly does more work than a bare for loop.

This is under vs2010. Not sure how other versions handle this.

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't a for loop be slower because of bound checking on the array?

No, the CLR can optimize that to 1 check if it can verify the bounds. Which makes

```
 int max = strings.Count - 1;
```

A bad optimization. In FX 1.1 it would have cost you. (It is incorrect too).

The `foreach` has to do a little more work (going through an Eumerator). Note the difference is small.

Comment: Hank int max = string.Count; is the right, -1 was a mistake, BUT int max DOES optimize. Take this new code I posted and try.

Comment: the foreach has to create an enumerator on each for, but the for has to do millions of bound checks on strings[i] unless the compiler did some magic there ...

Comment: but you have a point wiht the compiler optimization for the bound checking. I tried with moving the int i; out of the action, and it slowed down the for by 5%. So there must be some optimization on the i variable.

Comment: ok i now think that the compiler cannot optimize this loop like you thought becaus ethe collection is out of scope of the method that iterates over it (so another thread could change it), this is why int max does optimize (it skip reading the property on each iteration).

Comment: @Marino : just leave the property-inlining to the JIT. This is an old topic.

Comment: i tried but performance went down, so i reintroduced the variable... you should try it yourself, old topics may not be true anymore, or I am totally mistaken, but testing disproves what you are saying. if you disprove my testing then I will be able to believe. But believing to the JIT inliner is like believing in god, somebody will somebody won't.